# BasicFileAttributes confusion: what's the real creation time?

Tags: java

I'm automating processing of flat files received from a mainframe and am confused on creating and modified times.  The files are created on the mainframe then emailed to the required individuals.  The individuals then save the file from email (Outlook) and do whatever it is they do with them.

For that automation, the file will be processed automatically.  I need to let the user know when the last file was loaded and give them the option to load a newer file.

My issue is with the times:  I'm getting a creation date/time that is later than the lastmodified time.  Using this code:

```
 try {
        DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        DateFormat cstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        cstFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));

        Path filePath = Paths.get("C:/data/KWJFLTD.XLS");
        BasicFileAttributes basicAttr = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class);

        FileTime creationTime = basicAttr.creationTime();
        FileTime modifiedTime = basicAttr.lastModifiedTime();
        String cTime = creationTime.toString();
        String mTime = modifiedTime.toString();
        Date dc = utcFormat.parse(cTime);
        Date dm = utcFormat.parse(mTime);

        cTime = cstFormat.format(dc);
        mTime = cstFormat.format(dm);

        System.out.println("Creation Time:  " + cTime);
        System.out.println("Modified Time:  " + mTime);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FAULoad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ParseException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(FAULoad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I get this result:

```
Creation Time:  2015-06-24 15:25:12
Modified Time:  2015-06-24 02:28:05
```

I end up with a creation time **after** the last modified time.  Is this because the creation time is changed when it's saved from email?  In this situation, given that there's (theoretically) no modification going on since it was generated, would the last modified time be the same as the creation date?

Comment: why do you have two different dateformat objects?

Comment: It's just a guess but it might be that modification time was the time the content in general was last modified while creation time is the time _this specific_ file has been created. If you copy a file thus creation time (of the copy) might be after modification time (of the content). See here for example: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-files/how-can-the-date-created-be-later-than-the-date/9e625c0d-8694-4c8e-8a27-3ce74687aa53

Comment: @mackivelli:  One is for UTC, the other is CST...plus, I want to drop the decimal part of the seconds.

Comment: @Thomas: That was exactly the answer to my question.  I couldn't find that when I searched for it.  Set that as the answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Documentation](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-files/how-can-the-date-created-be-later-than-the-date/9e625c0d-8694-4c8e-8a27-3ce74687aa53) (the link relates to Win XP but most like also applies up to Win 10) the modification time is the time the file's content was last written while the creation time is the time a specific file has been created.

Thus if you copy a file the modification date would not change since no content has been written/changed but a new file (the copy) has been created and thus the creation time would be after the modification time.